# HAML - AngularJS - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, haml

I'm too new to everything I'm doing here, please help me out.

I have this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/onokiyo/4n6zucad/) in HTML, which I tried to implement in HAML and it's not returning the label.  In HAML, I got the ID back from customer.name_info.business_type as shown below.  However, if I changed to {{getBusinessTypeLabel(customer.name_info.business_type)}}, it didn't display anything at all.

getBusinessTypeLabel is a function in the controller which is being used in the whole app.

Before:

```
.form-group
  %label.col-sm-2.control-label Business Type: 
  .col-sm-10
    %p.form-control-static {{customer.name_info.business_type}}
```

After:

```
.form-group
  %label.col-sm-2.control-label Business Type: 
  .col-sm-10
    %p.form-control-static {{getBusinessTypeLabel(customer.name_info.business_type)}}
```

Thank you very much for any lead,

P.A.

Comment: You should '''- binding.pry''' in haml right above the function line and below the .col-sm-10 to confirm that function actually returns something on this page

Comment: Hi MilesStandfield, I'm too new to comprehend your suggestion about binding.  can you throw in an example?  TYVM.

Comment: Read these docs and install [pry-bug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug/blob/master/README.md) gem